# Function which only returns a value based on a the percentage param

Tags: python-3.x, percentage

Given a percentage of 0-100, how can one return a value "y", x% of the time.

For example, if I want to return a string "yes" 30% of the time

```
myfunc(30)

def myfunc(percentage):
   # Do something here that "yes" will return 30% of the time
   return "yes"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `random`

```py
import random

def myfunc(percentage):
    p = random.randint(0,100)
    if p <= percentage:
        print("Did something")
myfunc(30)
```